# How to extend Composer rest Server

Tags: rest, httpresponse, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I made a Hyperledger composer Network.
I want to see My function that have a query code.

for example,
My function' content is

```
/**
 * @param {hansung.ac.kr.transaction.selectUserByCertificateName}  tx  - the member to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
function selectUserByCertificateName (tx) {
  var idList = [];

  query("selectCertificateByName" , {targetName: tx.certificateName })
  .then(function (certificateList) {
     certificateList.forEach(function (certificate) {
     idList.push(certificate.ownerId);
     })
  }).then(function () {
     idList.forEach(function (id) {
        query("selectUserById" , {targetId: id })
        .then(function (userList){
         console.log(userList); 
        });
     })
  });

}
```

this case, I attempt to console.log.
I want to see this result(userList) in my angular page.

In angular, http.get method is used for receiveing rest-server data
but, I don't know how to editing composer-rest-server response format
I want to sending userList to rest Response.

How to extend Composer rest Server ?

if another way To get Data is exist,
please give advice

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the wrong approach you're doing. It looks like you want to query something from the custom `composer-rest-server` having access to your deployed Business Network.

As you want to build a REST query endpoint at the end, you have to implement a simple [Hyperledger Composer Query definition](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/query-language). `composer-rest-server` offers all your query definitions as a GET request.

To learn and understand I can highly recommend you [this Composer & REST server query tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries).
Another thing I'd like to recommend you is not to work with `console.log` at all in transaction processor functions. The logged results can only be seen when executed in a browser connection in Composer Playground *or* when the code is executed through unit/Cucumber tests.

Comment: Thank you,
But I want to query in My example transaction.

Comment: I want to query about different two table. 
so I will use my example transaction(query in transaction)
I know query in queries.qry that offers GET request.
But I need to query transaction function in model file .